# Resource use on a webpage

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, coldfusion

I have a webpage that uses javascript and ajax to call another page that processes one database record. The javascript uses a timer to "rest" prior to making another ajax request to the page.

My network team insists that this is causing a huge load on the system even though the page that is called takes less then a second to load if you load it directly.  I fail to see how I am loading the servers.  I am not sure if it is the web server or the database server takes the hit in performance.

Is this possible or are they smoking good stuff?  The network team thinks that since it makes calls every so often then that it has to be the culprit for the loss in performance.

As a work around I have thought about just adjusting the page that process the record to just refresh every 30 seconds to a minute which in theory would be the same thing that I am doing with the ajax request.  The only reason I set it up like this was to be able to have an on/off switch.

Question:  Are they right and how can I ensure that my pages do not hog resources.

Thanks

Here is the javascript

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn-go").click(Start);
    $("#test").click(Stop);
});

var timer;
var counter = 0;
var timeOut = 30000;
var pause = 10000;
var bit = 0;
var data = null;
//stops the process
function Stop(){
    bit = 1;
    $("#response").append('<br/>***Stopped at - '+ getTime() + ' ***');
    $("#response").append('<br/>***Records Processed - '+ counter + ' ***');
}
//Starts the process
function Start(){
    bit = 0;
    $("#response").append('<br/>***Started at - '+ getTime()+ ' ***');
    Step1();
}

function Step1(){
    counter++;
    $.post('Step1.cfm', setTimeout(finalStep, timeOut));//,  setTimeout(Step2, timeOut));
    return false;
}

//Final Step
function finalStep(){
    //alert(getTime());
    $("#response").append('<br/>record updated at - '+ getTime());

    if(bit != 1)
        {
            Step1();

        }

}

function getTime()
{
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    var minutes = now.getMinutes();
    var seconds = now.getSeconds();
    var time = hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
    return time;
}
```

webpage that process the record

```
<!--- the page checks the archive database table contact to see if any records match--->
<cfparam name="pblead" default="cfleadsource_prod">
<cfparam name="MARS" default="cfleadsource">

<cfquery name="GetRecord" datasource="#pblead#">
    select top 1 * from tmp_WirelessRepairListDec2014 where IsMatch = 1
    <!--- select * from contact where contactid = 2323924 --->
</cfquery>


<!-- check for phone matches-->
<cfquery name= "CheckPhone" datasource="cfLeadSourceArchive">
    select * from contact where phone='#GetRecord.phone#' or phone2 = '#GetRecord.phone#' or phone3 = '#GetRecord.phone#'
</cfquery>


<cfif CheckPhone.RecordCount eq 0><!--- no record found--->

    <!-- check for address matches-->
    <cfquery name="CheckAddress" datasource="cfLeadSourceArchive">
        select * from contact where mailingAddress = '#GetRecord.address#' or shippingAddress = '#GetRecord.locationAddress#'
    </cfquery>

        <cfif CheckAddress.RecordCount eq 0><!--- no record found set IsMatch to one for Archive Testing--->
            <cfquery name="SetForArchiveTest" datasource="#pblead#">
                update tmp_WirelessRepairListDec2014 set IsMatch = 2 where id = '#GetRecord.id#'
            </cfquery>

        <cfelse><!---address record found update database--->
            <!--update database 8 indicates that an address number matched-->
            <cfquery name="RecordFound" datasource = "#pblead#">
                update tmp_WirelessRepairListDec2014 set IsMatch = 8, cid = '#CheckAddress.contactid#', locationFound ='archive' where id = '#GetRecord.id#'
            </cfquery>
        </cfif>

<cfelse><!---phone record found update database--->
    <!--update database 9 indicates that a phone number matched-->
    <cfquery name="RecordFound" datasource = "#pblead#">
            update tmp_WirelessRepairListDec2014 set IsMatch = 9, cid = '#CheckPhone.contactid#', locationFound ='archive' where id = '#GetRecord.id#'
    </cfquery>
</cfif>
```

main webpage

```
<html>
<head>
<!--include link to jquery files-->
<script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="CheckArchive.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h3>Check list against archive for Wireless list</h3>
<button id="btn-go">Start</button><button id="test">Stop</button>
<hr/>
<div id="response"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest asking your network team to show you the data that justifies their opinion.  Looking at your code, selecting top 1 without an order by clause seems odd.

Comment: I do not use an order by simply because I am just going down a table from top to bottom.  No need to order because it just looks for the first `isMatch=1` and processes that record.  However now that you mention it I do need a catch or something to handle an end of database or no record found issue.

Comment: If you run the page without javascript and turn on debugging, do you see anything that looks resource intensive?

Comment: It doesn't look like the processor is passing any data back (ala cfreturn for cfc or straight raw text). Is your processor exempt from header and footer assembly (it should be)?

Comment: Also, because it's important. You need to be using cfqueryparam in all of your queries whenever you're passing data. Your "processor" is as very vulnerable to attack. https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfqueryparam

Comment: @danBracuk the processing pages has no javascript on it at all and I do not seen anything that would cause a load.

Comment: @cfqueryparam I am not sure what you mean by header and footer assembly.  I also agree that I should be using cfqueryparam but I chose not to since this is not public facing.  It is 100 percent internal.  It sits on and calls a server that has no external access.  So yes it can be attacked but it could only be attacked by an internal source.  If that happens my boss can deal with that problem. :)

Comment: When you visit step1.cfm manually, are the header and footer shown on your screen? If they are, you need to exempt them from it. Of course, I can't know what's contained within pre and post-request processing but since this page looks light, that's got me curious.

Comment: @cfqueryparam Nothing is shown.  Just a blank white page.  The "process record" page is the entire code.

Comment: Alright, that's all I was asking. I was thinking maybe application.cfc was sticking something in the header/footer.

Comment: *not public facing. It is 100 percent internal* @MarkHart - Unless there is a compelling reason to do otherwise, you should **always** use cfqueryparam. Protection against sql injection is actually just a side effect. The primary purpose of cfqueryparam (or bind variables) is to enhance database performance. Bind variables help databases reuse execution plans (which are costly to generate) when statements are executed multiple times. They improve overall database performance. So you are missing out on that by NOT using cfqueryparam (plus a few other benefits as well).

Comment: @Leigh I was not aware that it added in performance.  I thought it was just about sql injection.  That being said I will make the necessary changes to the code.  Perhaps that will increase the performance and make the network team happy.  Thank you! Any tidbits that I can incorporate in my everyday code to increase performance I always welcome.

Comment: (Edit) @MarkHart - Yes, it is a common misconception. While it is pretty "neat", as far as side effects go, it is not really the main purpose of bind variables. *increase the performance and make the network team happy* Bind variables help, but they are not a cure-all ;-) Your network guys need to give more specifics about the exact nature of "the problem", so you can determine if it IS a valid concern, and if so, how to address it.

Comment: Also, did you do some basic testing ie run the page and look at the network tab of your debugger to see how many http requests it triggers, check the times and db execution plans of the individual sql statements ? That will give a better indication of what is going on - and whether or not the network folks are correct.

Comment: Update: I found out more from the network team.  It seems that anytime I kick off a cfm page that does any high crunching on the SQL server it crashes the Cold Fusion server and/or the IIS server.  I am told that my pages kill port 80. So they tell me that anytime the sql server has to do a lot of processing then that is when I crash the system.

I personally do not think that it is my pages.  I believe that a process that runs ever 5 seconds and makes a call to a cfm page for db processing is the culprit. My users sometimes have 20 plus pages open and 40 people so 800 calls every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months of research we concluded that while it is a very simple plan it was so inefficient due to the number of records that were being compared.

I ended up moving the entire process to the DB and now just run a stored procedure to perform this task.

Thanks for everyones input.

Just discovered that the server handling this only had 4GB memory and was running a CF server, DB server, Web Server, handling the DNS and Active Directory